# How to pass a URL to an iframe dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm unable to pass the URL to an iframe dynamically. I checked several sources on the Internet, but none of them worked properly.

#### File *my-component.component.html*

```
            <iframe
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              src="{{ dynamicUrl }}"
              scrolling="auto"
            ></iframe>
```

#### File *my-component.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  dynamicUrl =
    'https://some-website.com/app/main/dashboards/63a0846ut7gxn0035c049e4?embed=true';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

The frame is not loading and in console I'm getting this error:

> core.mjs:7635 ERROR Error: NG0904: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

What’s the best approach?